# Task management app that can automatically create tasks based on event types

Tags: project-management

I've been using Asana to manage tasks for a marketing team. Overall, I love its functionality. But I find that a lot of our tasks are very similar, with only dates changing. They are set activities that need to be done by fixed people, at a fixed proximity to an event. They could be grouped into three or four event types.

E.g. For event type 'Small Event', I always need the following to happen:

- 4 weeks before the event, person X must create something.
- 3 weeks before the event, person Y must do something.
- 2 weeks before the event, person X must do something.

I'm looking for some way (preferably an app like Asana) to *not* have to create the list of tasks each time, as it is fairly time consuming, and it doesn't need to be. I want to tell it that I have an event coming up, and it generates all of the tasks that need to be done, when they are due, and then assigns those tasks to the standard people.

I've looked around at most other task management apps (producteev, todoist, etc.) and they don't seem to offer this either. I'm willing to look outside of mobile/web apps, but they would be used by a team, and so ease of use would need to be fairly high to ensure that they can and actually do use the software.

Budget: sell me a dream and I'll go for it. I'm happy for Web-based or Android apps.

Comment: I'm happy for Web based or Android

Comment: Thanks, I've integrated that with your question directly (to make it easier to spot). I've never worked with *Asana*, but please take a look at [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_25) on my site, and Ctrl-F for "Asana"; maybe one of those fits. I could imagine *Weekdone" or *Asana Quick Tasks* might do the job.

Comment: Hi Izzy. Sorry for the late reply. I looked at those apps, and a few of the others on the page, and they didn't seem to offer that functionality.

Comment: Sorry for that ­– but I couldn't know (hence the comment and not an answer). So it might well be there is no such app for Android at least (the 3 in my list are the only ones related to *Asana* I was able to find at GPlay).

Comment: I appreciate you help none the less!

Comment: Glad to read :) Anyway: there are more lists on my site which might prove helpful next time you're looking for something – hopefully with more luck :) Another raw idea: If any of those *Asana* apps offers support for *Tasker*, there might be a way to automate it that way. Or if they have a (web-) API to submit tasks, a little PHP script could help. Just in case nothing else turns up, to not leave you completely empty-handed. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Izzy. Will look into that. If only my PHP was up to scratch!

Comment: Well, not much I can do about that :) You let us know when you've found a solution, will you?

Comment: https://www.teamwork.com/ looks like it might pull it off.